# Set XSCF to automatically poweron a physical partition

Tags: solaris

I have a Fujitsu M-10 with one physical partition (PPAR).

The PPAR runs a Solaris 11 guest which automatically boots when the PPAR is powered on.

The problem is that if the M-10 is power cycled, the PPAR must be powered on manually via the XSCF, e.g. `poweron -p 00 -y`.

Is it possible to make PPAR 0 automatically power on when the M-10 regains power?

I have tried [setpowerschedule](http://jp.fujitsu.com/platform/server/sparc/manual/en/c120-e679/7.2.2.html) and I have both the `schedule=enable` and `recover=on` for PPAR 0, but the PPAR is still not powered on automatically after a power cycle.

Comment: How long did you wait to see if the PPAR powers up?  What's the power-up delay set to?  `showpowerupdelay`

Comment: `showpowerupdelay` reports 0 minutes delay. I have just power cycled the M-10 and waited 30 mins. The PPAR has not powered on.